# What Level of Superior Recovery Does the Monster-Creation Version Give?

Tags: character-creation, anima-beyond-fantasy

Pg. 285 of the Core Rulebook indicates that when creating creatures you can purchase Superior Magic Recovery for them at the cost of 30 DP with a requirement that they possess at least 5 Gnosis.  The section header indicates that the ability works the same as the creation advantage of the same name, which would be fine except that the Superior Magic Recovery advantage has three levels and it is unclear which one the DP version gets you.

So what level of recovery does that ability grant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above the table with all the powers you can select, is the text you paraphrase. The next sentence give us a clue...

> These abilities work exactly the same way as the creation advantages
>   that have the same name. All of them are equivalent to the more basic
>   abilities that are gained by investing points. [...]

So, as the book states, when they have levels, you gain the most basic of all levels. In this case, as if you spend one advantage point. So you will 'only' duplicate your Zeon recovery.

The latest spanish version (Core Exxet) has to say (in page 305):

> Estas habilidades actúan exactamente igual que las ventajas de
>   creación que llevan el mismo nombre. Todas ellas son equivalentes a
>   las capacidades más básicas que se consiguen invirtiendo puntos.

Which Google Translates into...

> These skills act exactly like the advantages of creating bearing the
>   same name. They are all equivalent to the most basic skills that are
>   achieved by investing points.

Comment: ah, so 'more basic' was a mistranslation of lowest level.  I really need to hunt down the Spanish version of the rulebook at some point.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this? Like, a quote from the Spanish rulebook?

Comment: Added edits, so you can see the Spanish version. If you are interested in the old edition of spanish Anima, I may be able to hunt it down, but I don't believe it will be much different...